# sum numeric values in a multidimentional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array like this in Javascript:

```
var scores = [
    {"firstName":"John", "value": 89},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "value": 151},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "value": 200},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "value": 22},
    {"firstName":"Anna","value": 60}
];
```

I would like to transform this array so that the values of similar first names are combined. My desired outcome is:

```
var scores = [
    {"firstName":"John", "value": 89},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "value": 173},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "value": 260}
];
```

Regards,

Comment: What have you already tried yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```js
var scores = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "value": 89
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "value": 151
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "value": 200
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "value": 22
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "value": 60
}];

var names = {};
var new_arr = [];

scores.forEach(function(entry) {
  if (names.hasOwnProperty(entry.firstName)) {
    new_arr[names[entry.firstName]].value += entry.value;
  } else {
    names[entry.firstName] = new_arr.length;
    new_arr.push({
      "firstName": entry.firstName,
      "value": entry.value
    });
  }
});

console.log(new_arr);
```

Comment: Seems fine to me. Anyone know why this might be downvoted?

Comment: You may leave your comment and let me know how to improve the code who downvoted it.

Comment: The solution iplus26 posted works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [],
    names = [],
    index;

var scores = [
   {"firstName":"John", "value": 89},
   {"firstName":"Peter", "value": 151},
   {"firstName":"Anna", "value": 200},
   {"firstName":"Peter", "value": 22},
   {"firstName":"Anna","value": 60}
];

scores.forEach(function (score) {
  index = names.indexOf(score.firstName);

  if (index === -1) {
     index = names.push(score.firstName) - 1;
     result.push({firstName: score.firstName, value: 0});
  }

  result[index].value += score.value;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step solution. First count all items. And second, format the result to the wanted style.

```js
var scores = [
    { "firstName": "John", "value": 89 },
    { "firstName": "Peter", "value": 151 },
    { "firstName": "Anna", "value": 200 },
    { "firstName": "Peter", "value": 22 },
    { "firstName": "Anna", "value": 60 }
];
var result = [],
    r0 = scores.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.firstName] = (r[a.firstName] || 0) + a.value;
        return r;
    }, {}), // { "John": 89, "Peter": 173, "Anna": 260 }
    i;
for (i in r0) {
    result.push({ firstName: i, value: r0[i] });
}
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```